# How to change splash icon size under min API 21

Tags: android

I using the drawable resource `splash_screen.xml` as my splash screen's icon, but the android:width and android:height require the min API 23, how to fix with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/splash_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: As an extension to Al-amins answer: You can have a copy of the drawable in `res/drawable-v23` where it contains the width and height (or any other customizations for api ≥23). Devices with older versions just won't look the same but you could scale the image as suggested for these devices.

Answer (score 2):

this is what i am using,
on `res/drawable/splash_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_splash_logo" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and on `res/drawable-v23/splash_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />

    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_splash_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: What is the difference? They look the same

Comment: a good ansewer. Thanks very mach

Answer (score 0):

For lower API levels, specifying width and height directly is **impossible**. you can only scale your icon